# How to remove hiss and static noise from a DVD

Tags: video-editor, noise-reduction

I got my VHS tapes converted to DVD. The video quality is reasonably good. However, there is a lot of hiss and static in the audio. Unfortunately, the original VHS is not usable anymore, so I can't digitize from scratch again. This is a personal video of family recordings.

The steps I tried are:

1. copy the DVD to PC. ( a get couple of .VOB file)
2. Extract and edit the audio file using Goldwave to remove noise. (the clean files are in .wav format)
3. replace the audio track on the original .VOB and create a new video file.

I could do the first 2 steps but have not succeeded in performing step 3 as I do not know how to replace the audio file.

I do not have to create .vob files. Any video format with new (edited/cleaned) audio is fine.

Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a program to download the files from your DVD. Then dump them in a video editor and replace the audio tracks. I believe Windows Video Maker would allow to do everything I am talking about. I sincerely never used vob files straight out of a DVD, but I believe any video editor would be able to support them.

Comment: I would use adobe encoder to split the audio from the video,  then use adobe's sound suite  (the name escapes me,  but its part of creative cloud) which has multiple configurable bandpass filters to remove the hiss, and finally edit them back together with premier pro into a cohesive file to lay down as a DVD track

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with both programs, but it sounds like once you have the video file and it's audio track (exported from adobe's sound suite), you should be able to easily import both of them into Premier and mute the original audio track, while enabling the fixed track.

Comment: I wonder if you can do everything from Premiere without the need of Encoder and the Sound suite. Have you tried Premiere's audio tools?

Comment: You would just delete the old audio track altogether in premiere.  Since all actions in premiere are non-destructive, the original footage remains untouched.  All that is actually changed is the rendering script (an XML file) built by premiere.  The sound tools in Premiere are quite extensive, but you get finer grained control in the sound suite. I suspect but can't prove that both GUI's use the same code behind the scenes

Comment: Microsoft Video Maker is not supported on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  the MS Video Maker is ok for small files but was unable to handle long recordings.  I tried other video editors and was able to merge sound and video

Answer (score 0):

After various trials trying to edit separate audio and video files, I realized that mixing such audio and video poses a problem of synchronization.

The only practical solution was to procure a dedicated Video editing software with capabilities to edit audio in the original file itself.

so I recommend not to spend time and energy in free software for any such project.